# Are kidney beans that split and wrinkle during soaking process safe to consume?

Tags: food-safety, beans, soaking

After 5 hours of soaking I find my dried kidney beans' skin wrinkled and some split in two, however my main concern is phytohaemagglutinin and the fact now that some beans are split open and lost their skin (shell) microbes have access to inside.

*Safe as in not causing any illnesses, upset stomach and life threatening situations.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Phytohaemagglutinin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phytohaemagglutinin) is found in the highest concentrations in uncooked red kidney beans and white kidney beans (also known as cannellini), and it is also found in lower quantities in many other types of green beans and other common beans (Phaseolus vulgaris), as well as broad beans (Vicia faba) such as fava beans. **Poisoning can be induced from as few as five raw beans.** The amount of phytohaemagglutinin can be reduced to safe levels by correct cooking (boiling for at least 30 minutes at 100 °C/ 212 °F). Insufficient cooking, such as in a slow cooker at 80 °C/ 176 °F can increase this danger and raise the available [haemagglutinating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemagglutination) units (hau) up to fivefold.
- Most microorganism, or [microbes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microorganism), can be greatly reduced by proper [cooking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooking#Food_safety).
- Low acid foods, such as beans that have been stored incorrectly, can be a source of [botulism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botulism#Prevention).

The above information is sourced from Wikipedia. The blog article: "[Crockpots, Slow Cooking Dried Beans & Phytohaemagglutinin](http://www.choosingvoluntarysimplicity.com/crockpots-slow-cooking-dried-beans-phytohaemagglutinin/)" suggests:

1. Soak the dried beans in water for at least five hours (some recommend soaking the beans for at least twelve hours)
2. Discard the soaking water which will contain leached out toxins
3. Rinse the beans and cover them with fresh water
4. Boil the beans (rapid boil) for at least ten minutes
5. It is then safe to add the beans to the slow cooker and proceed with the recipe

It is important to do your own research and not rely on any single source of advice.